# "text index required for $text query" when using collection.find

Tags: pymongo

I am trying to make a code that searches by the query. But when I does it, it raises `OperationFailure text index required for $text query` Why is this happening

```py
postlist = <collection>.find({'$text': {'$search': f'"{query}"'}})
```

This is the code (used some normal collection in `collection`)

Comment: Did you create a text index?

Comment: No. Should I create a text index?

Comment: Yes - see my answer for info.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a text on your search field in order to use full-text search.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/